# Receiving zero byte audio stream when doing Amazon Polly text to speech conversions

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'm trying to do text to speech conversions using Amazon Web Services Polly and the AWS SDK for C#.  I've attempted a very basic conversion:

```
AmazonPollyClient client = new AmazonPollyClient("secret", "secret", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechRequest request = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
request.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3;
request.Text = "This is my first conversion";
request.TextType = TextType.Text;
request.VoiceId = VoiceId.Nicole;
Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(request);
```

I receive an `HTTP 200 OK` response (no exceptions are thrown) however the audio stream is empty:

[image: Empty audio stream 1]
[image: Empty audio stream 2]

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned `AudioStream` has no length until you read it somewhere, such as into a file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Polly;
using Amazon.Polly.Model;
namespace AwsPollySO1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AmazonPollyClient client = new AmazonPollyClient("yourID", "yourSecretKey", RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            SynthesizeSpeechRequest request = new SynthesizeSpeechRequest();
            request.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Mp3;
            request.Text = "This is my first conversion";
            request.TextType = TextType.Text;
            request.VoiceId = VoiceId.Nicole;
            SynthesizeSpeechResponse response = client.SynthesizeSpeech(request);
            Console.WriteLine("ContentType: " + response.ContentType);
            Console.WriteLine("RequestCharacters: " + response.RequestCharacters);
            FileStream destination = File.Open(@"c:\temp\myfirstconversion.mp3", FileMode.Create);
            response.AudioStream.CopyTo(destination);
            Console.WriteLine("Destination length: {0}", destination.Length.ToString());
            destination.Close();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe all you have to do is flush the stream before you save (or even see length)

```
response.AudioStream.CopyTo(destination);
destination.Flush();
```

see if that does the trick for you.